# Transit in Newark (EWR) from Montreal (YUL) to Stockholm (ARN) with checked baggage

Tags: transit

I will be flying out of Montreal (YUL) to Stockholm (ARN) with a 9h transit in Newark Liberty Airport (EWR). The problem is that I will have a lot of luggage, three checked bags to be precise. My first haul will be a United flight and then for my flight to Sweden, I will fly with SAS.

I wonder if anyone knows if I can drop my bags off directly after baggage claim or if I need to wait until SAS open their bag drop a couple of hours before the flight. How does it work? Does anyone also know how it works with the luggage if I need to transfer in between terminals? This is my first time flying internationally out of Canada with a transit in the US.

Comment: Are the flights on the same ticket? If so, you can likely have them checked all the way through to Stockholm and not have to collect them in Newark. (You will clear US customs before you get on the plane in Montreal.)

Comment: The situation will be different the other way around though.